# How do I keep header with no data in DataTable from react-data-table-component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

My goal is to have the table head whether or not there is data, but I also don't want a `noDataComponent`, because the idea I want to execute requires there to be none. I can't seem to find any information online about preventing the head from going away when there is no data, only other components that do that natively.

```js
  <DataTable
      columns={columns}
      data={data}
      actions={actions}
      progressPending={loading}
      noDataComponent={<></>}
  />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply set `persistTableHead` to true.

```js
<DataTable
      columns={columns}
      data={data}
      actions={actions}
      progressPending={loading}
      persistTableHead={true}
/>
```

Description from the [doc](https://react-data-table-component.netlify.app/?path=/docs/api-props--page#general-properties):

> persistTableHead: Show the table head (columns) even when progressPending is true. Note: The noTableHead will always hide the table head (columns) even when using persistTableHead

Comment: Could you link the docs for me? I looked for them everywhere and couldn't find them!

Comment: np, I've edited the link into the answer!